# Why these sentences doesn't have auxiliary word in it?

Tags: questions, auxiliary-verbs

In these sentences, why isn't there an auxiliary verb? I would expect that there will be one after "Who" in both sentences:

1) Who cooks when Karen and Andy have friends round for dinner,

2) Who chatted to people online at the weekend?

Comment: Why on earth would you expect auxiliaries just because the sentences start with _who_? There's no reason whatsoever to have auxiliaries in either of those two sentences.

Comment: Present tense (_cooks_) and past tense (_chatted_) are true tenses -- the only ones in English -- and take inflections (_-s, -ed_) instead of auxiliary verbs. Questions that **do** contain auxiliary verbs undergo subject-auxiliary inversion (_Who are they inviting?_); and they may require _Do_-Support (_Who does Karen cook for?_). But this doesn't happen with questions where (a) the _Wh_-word is the subject (as here), **and** (b) there is a single, tensed main verb (as here).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you could say 'Who does the cooking when Karen.....' and 'Who was it who chatted to people online...'. But the sentences make perfectly good sense as they are written.

Comment: Those versions don't have auxiliary verbs in them either; they use _does_ and _was_ in their non-auxiliary senses.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I thought that when I wrote it, but I am rather puzzled by the question.

Comment: When *who* is the direct object, then the question form is: 1) Who **does** Alan love? A) He loves Anne. But 2) Who loves Anne? A) Alan loves her. *Who* in 2) is the subject. Likewise "Who do Karen and Andy cook for?" and "Who did the people online chatted to?"